# How to access Microsoft Graph's services with service-user credentials

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a special service account in AAD that I want to use to send email notifications to users.

In asp.net core 2 web app, how do I get access token for that service account?
The samples I've seen uses user's identity, but that is not my case.

I will have probably some background process, so there cannot be any user interactivity.

Comment: Are you using MSAL, ADAL or you don't care?

Comment: Did you check these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto:  I don't care since I don't know the practical difference, but I'm confused that in App Registraion Portal I have to specify in Edit App/Platform/Web redirect uri. Whatever redirect uri  I specify, it will work with MSAL resp ADAL api, or I need to listen on ther uri actually?

Comment: @juunas: I didn't, they look useful. thanks.

Comment: They are two different methods of authentication and application registration is different. You should read on both since a token for one doesn't work for the other and there are different use cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will have probably some background process, so there cannot be any user interactivity.

you could use [OAuth 2 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-grant-in-AzureAd). **Note:** The resource owner password grant doesn't provide consent and doesn't support MFA either. Detailed tutorial, you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/). Moreover, you could use ADAL to retrieve the access_token instead of constructing the `HttpClient` by yourself.

The code for acquire the token via ADAL would look like:

```
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com","<clientId>", new UserPasswordCredential("<userName>", "<password>"));
```

Moreover, as juunas commented that you could use the service to service scenario and use the application permissions instead of the user delegated permissions. The code would look like this:

```
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", new ClientCredential("<clientId>", "<clientSecrets>"));
```

For your AAD app on Azure Portal, you need to configure the required permissions for accessing Microsoft Graph API as follows:

[image]

**Note:** For [Send mail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail) Microsoft graph API, you need to set the related permission. For Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow, you need to choose the delegated permission **Send mail as a user** (Mail.Send). While for client credential flow, you need to choose the application permission **Send mail as any user** (Mail.Send), then click grant permissions (this permission needs global admin to consent).

After retrieved the access_token, you could use [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to communicate with Microsoft Graph API to send the email. The initialization for `GraphServiceClient` would look like this:

```html
//initialize the GraphServiceClient instance
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    var token = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                }));
```